# Accessing the STM32L412KB Serial Wire Debugger (SWD) Connections (Novice User)

Tags: usb, stm32, st-link

I am attempting to program an STM32L412KB device using ST-Link/V2-1, a Raspberry Pi 3B+ and OpenOCD software.

To do this however, I require access to the SWDIO connection and the SWDCLK connection of the ST-Link on the STM32. From looking at this [diagram of the connections](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/e3/0e/88/05/e8/74/43/a0/DM00231744.pdf/files/DM00231744.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00231744.pdf), I am struggling to see a way of accessing these connections. Pins PA13 and PA14 are used on other boards but are inaccessible here. I am thinking the only way is through the micro USB port. If I then plug in a micro USB cable to the device, which pins on the larger end represent the SWDIO and SWCLK so I can then connect them to the complimentary pins on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: What do you want to archieve? Do you want to program the uC which is installed on this nuclei board? If yes you do not need to connect anything. What is the use of the RPi? Is it used as a computer where you compile your code?

Comment: So I have a binary file with code that I've created before on an stm32 board. I have then placed the binary file on the RPi. I then want to use the RPi to transfer the binary file into the STM32's flash memory using ST-Link.

Comment: The board described in your link has an embedded ST-LINK built in. If you search the pdf file for "SWD" you will also find a connector for SWD.

Comment: Indeed, use the built in stlink that is why it is there.  Openocd might want you to refer to it as a v2-1 or something, look up the USB PID

Comment: @ElliotAlderson what for. It is already connected. You need only to connect the USB. All SWD lines are connected on that bosard

Comment: @P__J__ Exactly my point. What is the OP trying to do??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need stlink flash utility - otherwise you will need to manually send the gdb commands.

How to make the stlink flasher:

```
sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev git
git clone https://github.com/texane/stlink stlink.git
cd stlink.git
make
cd flash
sudo cp st-flash /usr/bin
cd ..
sudo cp *.rules /etc/udev/rules.d
sudo restart udev
```

and then you can flash your nucleo board:

```
st-flash write yourfile.bin 0x8000000
```

or using the openocd

```
 openocd -f board/stm32<yourboard>.cfg -c "yourfile.bin exit 0x08000000"
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question which was actually asked.  The asker is using OpenOCD, which *also* supports this board's on-chip SWD adapter.  There is no reason to change software tools.

Comment: @ChrisStratton using openOCD just to program the device is an overkill. To use OpenOCD with STlink you need the driver and the correct udev rules. So 80% is common.

Comment: Actually with the board in question all you have to do is copy the file to the drive it emulates alongside the stlink interface.  But none of this answers the question which was asked.

Comment: @ChrisStratton So please explain what  the question is. I think even OP does not know. But it was explained in the answer to my question: *So I have a binary file with code that I've created before on an stm32 board. I have then placed the binary file on the RPi. I then want to use the RPi to transfer the binary file into the STM32's flash memory using ST-Link.* My answer answers the question. If you know better what OP wants write your own answer

Comment: This is great, exactly what I've been looking to do. Unfortunately, my device (the STM32L412KB) is unrecognised by openocd at the moment so I am trying to get the st-flash utility to work. Many thanks for your help, it is sending me down the right track. Apparently a fix exists: https://community.platformio.org/t/default-linker-script-fails-on-stm32l412-fix-included/6019/3 but I am unsure where to implement it.

Comment: @arry_h You need to clone the openOCD, modify the C file as in the link. Then you need to run configure and rebuild the openOCD. It is not an easy task if you do not have much experience with `autoconf` and `make`. I advice to cross build it on your PC (and having the RPi as the target)  as the build on the RPi will take severals hours. If your PC OS is windows it will be even more dificut as you need to boild under cygwin (or similar linux like environment)

Comment: That's really great, thank you. I'll give it a go.